# How do I show that there is a number $c$ between $0$ and $x$ such that $\frac{(1+x)^n-1}{x}=n(1+c)^{n-1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Show that there is a number $c$ between $0$ and $x\neq 0$ such that
$$\frac{(1+x)^n-1}{x}=n(1+c)^{n-1}.$$

I don't even know where to start. It sounds like [intermediate theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) could be applied or is it an application of [Taylor's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)?

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem? Apply it to the function $f(y)=(1+y)^n$ and consider $f(x)-f(0)$.

Comment: That was neat! Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Apply the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) to the function $f(y)=(1+y)^n$ and consider $f(x)-f(0)$.